# How to install latest Tomcat7 using yum on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yum, installation, tomcat7

I'd like to install the latest (7.0.53) Tomcat on an AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux.  If I were to do "sudo yum install tomcat7 -y", I would only get version 7.0.47, as shown by " yum list tomcat7".  I could manually download the tar file and manually install, but since I want to automate this problem on a number of servers, that is not really suitable.

If I wanted the latest MySQL instead of what AWS has in its repository, I can do this (second line just to verify the repo is added):

```
sudo yum localinstall http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el6.rpm -y
sudo yum repolist enabled | grep mysql 
sudo yum install mysql-server -y
```

I am guessing that there might be a similar repo that might allow me to do similar for Tomcat7, but I have not been able to find a URL for one.  Does such a thing exist?

Is there some other method of installing a more recent Tomcat7 on AWS using yum?

Comment: Unless you have a specific need, you'll usually be better off sticking with the package manager. Amazon tests and supports packages in their repos to make sure they work with Amazon Linux.

Comment: I would like to, but Amazon is way behind on many packages.  For MySQL, the supported version is 5.5.37, well behind the current 5.6.17.  If AWS kept up, I would happily use their default repo, but given they do not, I want the option to stay as up-to-date as possible.

Comment: 5.5.37 is not "well behind" 5.6.17. It's the latest release of the 5.5 line and was released under two months ago. Again, unless you have a specific need, stick with the main repos. Stability can be valuable, and AWS is quick with security updates.